# Compiling to javascript is not needed in CDK typescript project?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

While I develop sample App by using `CDK`I come up with some questions.
I change `stack.ts` in my project,and then `cdk synth` and `cdk deploy`. it seems compiling to js didn't needed in my project

when I see `cdk.json` following is specified.

`"app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/cdk.ts",`

It seems that cdk.ts is endpoint of my stack.and it seems that they are no problem even if I work only in typescript.

compiling to javascript is not needed in cdk development ? Are there any problems of this ?
If I misunderstand some essential things, will you please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is using [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node):

> ts-node is a TypeScript execution engine and REPL for Node.js.

> It JIT transforms TypeScript into JavaScript, enabling you to directly execute TypeScript on Node.js without precompiling.